# Incorrect syntax near '>'. in a case statement - can't figure out why. Is there anything I'm missing? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

```
SELECT field1, field2,
        Budget = CASE field2
         WHEN field2> 20.00 THEN 'Expensive'
          WHEN field2 BETWEEN 10.00 AND 19.99 THEN 'Moderate'
          WHEN field2< 10.00 THEN 'Inexpensive'
          ELSE 'Unknown'
        END
FROM table1
```

The table exists. The fields exist. But these are underlined in red:
<
BETWEEN
AND

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first "field2" after "CASE"

```
SELECT field1, field2,
        Budget = CASE
         WHEN field2 > 20.00 THEN 'Expensive'
          WHEN field2 BETWEEN 10.00 AND 19.99 THEN 'Moderate'
          WHEN field2 < 10.00 THEN 'Inexpensive'
          ELSE 'Unknown'
        END
FROM table1
```

EDIT: If your cases are constant, you can use different syntax.

```
SELECT field1, field2,
        Budget = CASE field2
         WHEN 20 THEN 'Expensive'
          WHEN 15 THEN 'Moderate'
          WHEN 10 THEN 'Inexpensive'
          ELSE 'Unknown'
        END
FROM table1
```

This obviously works better for integers.